# Squaring and multithreading in c

Tags: c, multithreading, square-root

im writing a program that uses 8 threads to square numbers from 1 - 10000. I have most of my code already written, but my question is how would I go about specifying which threads square which numbers. I am also new too multithreading. to clarify:

Im squaring the numbers from 1 to 100000 using 8 threads and writing them into a file. The opening the file and closing the file is okay, but writing each square from each thread is part of the equation here. This is my first program using pthread so I assumed that you needed to tell each thread what number to square in order

ideally I want:

thread 1: 1^2

thread 2: 2^2

thread 3: 3^2

etc through 10000...

in my main function, the code that creates the function and then waits for the threads to finish is this:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
    printf("Main here. Creating thread %luu\n", i);
    status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, square_root_integer, (void *) i);
    if (status != 0){
        printf("Error: pthread_create returned error code %0ld\n", status);
        exit (-1);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++){
    if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL)){
        printf("Thread %lu failed to join\n",i);
    }
}
```

the void function that the threads will run is this:

```
void *square_integer(void *tid)
```

So somehow in the main function I need to pass the number that needs to be squared to the "square_integer" function.

Any help would be great and if you guys need more info let me know!

Comment: Your title says 'square roots'; some of the commentary says 'squares'.  The function says 'square roots' again.  Which is it?  You also mention 8 threads and yet discuss 10,000 threads too — again, what are you up to?

Comment: sorry guys, its late, I edited the post. Im printing the numbers into a file, which is the code I have already written. Im squaring the numbers from 1 to 100000 using 8 threads. This is my first program using pthread so I assumed that you needed to tell each thread what number to square in order.

Answer (score 0):

Have thread 1 do the computation for the numbers 1, 1+8, 1+16, 1+24, ...
and thread 2 for the numbers 2, 2+8, 2+16, 2+24, ..., 2 + 8*n , ...
and thread 3 for the numbers 3, 3+8, 3+16, 3+24, ..., 3 + 8*n , ...
and so on.

This way all the numbers get covered and the work gets pretty evenly distributed among the threads.